# Import "ckeditor.fields" could not be resolved

Tags: django, django-models, ckeditor

I am trying to install ckeditor in my django forms. I seem to have no problem with the pip install django-ckeditor however once it is installed and I have added it to my settings, I can not import RichTextEditor in my models.py file. The error that comes up is 'Import "ckeditor.fields" could not be resolved'.

Here is the code:
settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
```

Comment: You are trying to import `RichTextUploadingField `from `ckeditor.fields` it seems. update other code as well

Comment: Hey Sunil, thanks for getting back to me. What do you mean by this? can you expand please.

Comment: Run python manage.py migrate and collectstatic

Answer (score 1):

Install or add django-ckeditor to your python path.

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

Add `ckeditor` to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Run the collectstatic management command: `python manage.py collectstatic`